# Changed settings, now slow startups and USB not working

Tags: partitioning, usb, mouse

I am a first day ubuntu user. I really want to like it but I have had major issues. Right after installing I realize my RAT 7 mouse was not fully compatible and out took me 2 days to fix it. In doing so, 4/6 USB drives stopped working, and during startup I get stuck on the mobo splash screen for a long time before the mouse and keyboard light up and start working. I have tried reinstalling ubuntu already and the usbs do not work on live ubuntu. I'm not sure what information I should give. I'm very very new to ubuntu. My motherboard is asrock z97 extreme 6. 16gb ram. Intel i7 4790k. I have googled for the last 3 days with no progress. Thank you for any help. My partitions have / on an ssd. And /home /swap and /usr on an hdd.

Answer (score 0):

Ok well I fixed one problem and found a work around for another. To fix the USBs I used the clear CMOS button on my motherboard. That was literally the only thing that would work. As for the slow startup, unplugging the power cable for 5 minutes, plugging it back in and booting up fixed it. It now passes the motherboard splash screen in under 2 seconds. Only problem is the slow boot problem congress back every so often and I have to drain the power again.

Answer (score 0):

Try unplugging the power cord and pressing the start button for 30 secs (discharges the capacitor) - for me,  gets everything working again.

I have the same problem with a z87 extreme 6.   It seems that every time i update the kernel or grub the problem comes back (both usb problems and slow boot).